# Drop down menu with jQuery (progressive enhancement)

Tags: jquery

I was hoping that you can help me with this... I want to create a drop down menu with jQuery and it works perfectly with the javascript enabled in the browser. Now I want it to work when the javascript is turned of and I'm not quite sure how to do that.

I have the code here so that you can see for yourself.

**My html page with the lists:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery-1.6.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="p6.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <ul id="menu">

        <li><a href="#">What's new?</a>
          <ul class="active">
        <li><a href="#">Weekly specials</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Last night's pics!</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Users' comments</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">Member extras</a>
          <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Premium Celebrities</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">24-hour Surveillance</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
          <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Privacy Statement</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Terms and Conditions</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

**and my .js file**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#menu > li > ul').hide().click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    });

    $('#menu > li').toggle(function(){
    $(this).find('ul').slideDown();
    },function(){
    $(this).find('ul').slideUp();
    });

});
```

Thank you for your time!

Any help will be appreciated!

J

Answer (score 1):

If the javascript is turned off your only solution for a dropdown menu is using a `<select>` or :hover event and try to customize it with css

JS turned off == no Javascript, no Jquery, just plain HTML and CSS

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with just html and css for more modern browsers using the "hover" pseudoclass (i.e. 6 and similar don't respect the hover pseudoclass except on a tags). Something like this:

```
ul#menu li ul {
    display:none
}
ul#menu:hover li ul {
    display:block
}
```

Comment: More details on css menus in this alistapart article: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/horizdropdowns/